# Import Cling Demo

Tags: java, android, upnp

I want to import cling demo into Android Studio, but there isn't the file folder named build.gradle. I Add it as the Maven project, but there are some errors in the java files. The errors say cannot resolve some symbols, such as  `AndroidUpnpServiceImpl`, Service Type and so on, which are defined in the cling-core.jar. Actually, I have add the dependency in the pom.xml according to the read me. Could you tell me how to solve this problem?